# Creating a many to many relationship in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is a simplified example of what I am trying to achieve, I'm relatively new to Rails and am struggling to get my head around relationships between models.

I have two models, the `User` model and the `Category` model. A user can be associated with many categories. A particular category can appear in the category list for many users. If a particular category is deleted, this should be reflected in the category list for a user.

In this example:

My `Categories` table contains five categories:

```
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
| ID | Name                       |
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
| 1  | Sports                     | 
| 2  | News                       |
| 3  | Entertainment              |
| 4  | Technology                 |
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

My `Users` table contains two users:

```
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
| ID | Name                       |
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
| 1  | UserA                      | 
| 2  | UserB                      |
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

> UserA may choose Sports and Technology as his categories
>
> UserB may choose News, Sports and Entertainment
>
> The sports category is deleted, both UserA and UserB category lists reflect the deletion

I've toyed around with creating a `UserCategories` table which holds the ids of both a category and user. This kind of worked, I could look up the category names but I couldn't get a cascading delete to work and the whole solution just seemed wrong.

The examples of using the belongs_to and has_many functions that I have found seem to discuss mapping a one-to-one relationship. For example, comments on a blog post.

- How do you represent this many-to-many relationship using the built-in Rails functionality?
- Is using a separate table between the two a viable solution when using Rails?

Comment: Actually, there's nothing wrong with using `UserCategory` model, it's even desirable in most cases. You just need to use `User.has_many :categories, through: :user_categories`. Maybe, a better name could be found though.

Comment: For others, there is a good rails cast here about the subject: http://railscasts.com/episodes/47-two-many-to-many

Answer (score 194, accepted):

You want a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship. The guide does a great job of describing how this works with charts and everything:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association

You will end up with something like this:

```
# app/models/category.rb
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end

# app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end
```

Now you need to create a join table for Rails to use. Rails will not do this automatically for you. This is effectively a table with a reference to each of Categories and Users, and no primary key.

Generate a migration from the CLI like this:

```
bin/rails g migration CreateCategoriesUsersJoinTable
```

Then open it up and edit it to match:

#### For Rails 4.0.2+ (including Rails 5.2):

```
def change
  # This is enough; you don't need to worry about order
  create_join_table :categories, :users

  # If you want to add an index for faster querying through this join:
  create_join_table :categories, :users do |t|
    t.index :category_id
    t.index :user_id
  end
end
```

#### Rails < 4.0.2:

```
def self.up
  # Model names in alphabetical order (e.g. a_b)
  create_table :categories_users, :id => false do |t|
    t.integer :category_id
    t.integer :user_id
  end

  add_index :categories_users, [:category_id, :user_id]
end

def self.down
  drop_table :categories_users
end
```

With that in place, run your migrations and you can connect Categories and Users with all of the convenient accessors you're used to:

```
User.categories  #=> [<Category @name="Sports">, ...]
Category.users   #=> [<User @name="UserA">, ...]
User.categories.empty?
```

Comment: One additional tip: create a composite index for the table. More here http://stackoverflow.com/a/4381282/14540

Comment: @kolrie Great point; I added to the example here for the sake of being thorough. Cheers!

Comment: dumb question, does this mean it's necessary to create a new model?

Comment: has_and_belongs_to_many does not need/create model.  If you need to work directly with the relation or need to add attributes to the relationship, you should use has_many :through option. Follow the link in the answer for detailed info.

Comment: Another thing I noticed is the naming convention of the joining table.  It has to be alphabetically ordered.  Using the above example, the table name has to be categories_users and not users_categories.  "c" before "u" in this case.

Comment: I do this and can see the join-table is created in the schema but I get NoMethodError when I run `User.categories` etc. Any ideas what I could be missing?

Comment: @SagarPandya `categories` is a method on an instance of `User`, not the class.

Comment: Why doesn't the categories_users table have an id? (`:id => false do |t|`)

Comment: @ashwood You don't need a primary key because there's only a single instance of the relationship between.

Answer (score 17):

The most popular is 'Mono-transitive Association', you can do this:

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :book_authors
  has_many :authors, through: :book_authors
end

# in between
class BookAuthor < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :author
end

class Author < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :book_authors
  has_many :books, through: :book_authors
end
```

> A has_many :through association is often used to set up a many-to-many
>   connection with another model. This association indicates that the
>   declaring model can be matched with zero or more instances of another
>   model by proceeding through a third model. For example, consider a
>   medical practice where patients make appointments to see physicians.
>   Ref.: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Answer (score 8):

Just complementing coreyward's answer above:
If you already have a model that has a `belongs_to`, `has_many` relation and you want to create a new relation `has_and_belongs_to_many` using the same table you will need to:

```
rails g migration CreateJoinTableUsersCategories users categories
```

Then,

```
rake db:migrate
```

After that, you will need to define your relations:

**User.rb:**

```
class Region < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end
```

**Category.rb**

```
class Facility < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

In order to populate the new join table with the old data, you will need to in your console:

```
User.all.find_each do |u|
  Category.where(user_id: u.id).find_each do |c|
    u.categories <<  c
  end
end
```

You can either leave the `user_id` column and `category_id` column from the Category and User tables or create a migration to delete it.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to add additional data *on the relationship*, the `has_many :things, through: :join_table` may be what you're looking for. Often times, though, you won't need to additional metadata (like a role) on a join relationship, in which case `has_and_belongs_to_many` is definitely the simplest way to go (as in the accepted answer for this SO post).

However, let's say, you're building a forum site where you have several forums and need to support users holding different roles within each forum they participate in. It might be useful to allow for tracking how a user is related to a forum on the join itself:

```rb
class Forum
  has_many :forum_users
  has_many :users, through: :forum_users

  has_many :admin_forum_users, -> { administrating }, class_name: "ForumUser"
  has_many :viewer_forum_users, -> { viewing }, class_name: "ForumUser"

  has_many :admins, through: :admin_forum_users, source: :user
  has_many :viewers, through: :viewer_forum_users, source: :user
end

class User
  has_many :forum_users
  has_many :forums, through: :forum_users
end

class ForumUser
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :forum

  validates :role, inclusion: { in: ['admin', 'viewer'] }

  scope :administrating, -> { where(role: "admin") }
  scope :viewing, -> { where(role: "viewer") }
end
```

And your migration would look something like this

```rb
class AddForumUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  create_table :forum_users do |t|
      t.references :forum
      t.references :user

      t.string :role

      t.timestamps
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Side note: here's how you can add relationships to records once you've set up the relationship.

```
category1.users << user1
user2.categories << category2
```

Here's how to delete them

```
category1.users.delete(user1)
user2.categories.delete(category2)
```