# Generating a model with many to many in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, code-generation

Is there a way to generate a Rails model with a many to many relationship predefined? I know how to add it to the Active Record after the fact but it would be nice to have it defined in the DB migration and the Active Record model right off the bat.

Answer (score 23):

Remember that you do not want an id for the join table, so make sure to add `:id => false |t|`

```
create_table assemblies_parts, :id => false do |t|
  t.integer :assembly_id
  t.integer :part_id
end
```

If you use rails

```
rails generate model Assemblies_parts assembly:references part:references
```

you will have two indexes, but what you want is

```
# Add table index
add_index :assemblies_parts, [:assembly_id, :part_id], :unique => true
```

**UPDATE**

- For Rails 5 use [`create_join_table` instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32201949/what-is-the-behaviour-of-create-join-table-of-activerecordmigration) to create that (id-less) table.

Comment: What is the benefit of using create_join_table? As the "old" syntax still works fine and is imho not less comprehensible.

Comment: @Felix, possibly to avoid adding the odd `, :id => false`

Comment: I see. Makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this reference from the Rails Guides.[Here is the link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_and_belongs_to_many-association). Also you will need to manually create the join table for those models using a migration.

e.g

```
    create_table :assemblies_parts, :force => true do |t|
      t.integer :assembly_id
      t.integer :part_id
    end
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have read that guide. Like I mentioned to another responder, I was just wondering if the generate model script could handle it in one step, and it looks like it can't so that's fine...would've been nice though. ;p

Comment: yeah I dont think it can be done automatically. If I discover a short cut I will post it here :).

Answer (score 1):

Please look at this question first: [Creating a many-to-many relationship in Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120703/creating-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-rails-3).

In addition, I would recommend next book ["Ruby on Rails 3 Tutorial: Learn Rails by Example"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321743121) for a better understanding of `ActiveRecord` relations.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have read the guide that post links to.  I was just wondering if the generate model script could handle it in one step, looks like no.