# Rails 3 HABTM one-liner

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, many-to-many, model-associations, has-and-belongs-to-many

I need a one-liner to generate a has_and_belongs_to_many join table or else I will go back to Django for its simpler many-to-many constructs.

**rails 3 generate model article_tags** [..]

```
Models

# article.rb
has_many :articles_tags
has_many :tags, :through => :articles_tags

# tag.rb
has_many :articles_tags
has_many :articles, :through => :articles_tags

# article_tag.rb
belongs_to :tag
belongs_to :article
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ohh wait haha, I think this might do the trick:

```
rails g model articles_tags article:references tag:references --no-id --no-timestamps
```

I wonder if there is anyway to suppress the model file's creation (article_tags.rb) so that I can just use the standard has_and_belongs_to_many syntax *without having to specify a :through param*? I'm looking for the ultimate one-liner: Tip of the hat to anyone who can improve the above one-liner to enable **only the use of has_and_belongs_to_many syntax without a join model**! Else, I'm going back to Django, with it's built-in ManyToManyFields.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're looking for the standard has_and_belongs_to_many:

```
# article.rb
has_and_belongs_to_many :tags

# tag.rb
has_and_belongs_to_many :articles
```

Your join table would be called `articles_tags`, and need just contain two columns, `article_id` and `tag_id` (no `id` column needed since it isn't a model).

This is in the [Rails Guide to Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html). I highly recommend becoming familiar with the Rails Guides.

It's almost too simple for a generator. All you need are two empty model classes and the join table, which would be defined in a migration like so:

```
def self.up
  create_table :articles_tags, :id => false do |t|
    t.integer :article_id
    t.integer :tag_id
  end
end

def self.down
  drop_table :articles_tags
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this is still of interest after so much time, but I think you can take a look at https://github.com/zealot128/ruby-habtm-generator: it's a Rails generator that generates the correct migration for the HABTM table.

Answer (score 0):

Using generate will create two indexes

Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/9825571/643500