# What is the behaviour of create_join_table of ActiveRecord::Migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, join

I've discovered a nice way to generate join tables for my HABTM relationships in my Rails app.

```
rails g migration CreateJoinTable table1 table2
```

This generates an `ActiveRecord::Migration` that employs the method `create_join_table`

I'm wondering what this wonderful mysterious method does. I guess it makes a table (probably without an `id` field) that has a column for table1 foreign key and a column for table2 foreign key, but does the table have any other features?. My habit for join tables has always been to add a unique index across both those columns so that a relationship between a record in table1 and a record in table2 cannot be entered twice.

My question boils down to: If I use `create_join_table` do I need to keep adding that unique index, or does this method do that for me (I think it should)?

The [documentation I usually look at](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html) doesn't go into this sort of detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out it doesn't do any more than the basics I described in the question. I found this out simply by running the migration and seeing what ends up in `db/schema.rb`

For those interested, to get the unique index do this:

```
class CreateJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_join_table :posts, :users
    add_index :posts_users, [:post_id, :user_id], unique: true, name: 'index_posts_users'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 8):

Called without any block, `create_join_table` just creates a table with two foreign keys referring to the two joined tables.

However, you can actually pass a block when you call the method to do any additional operations (say, adding indexes for example). From the Rails doc:

```
create_join_table :products, :categories do |t|
  t.index :product_id
  t.index :category_id
end
```

Have a look at [`create_join_table` documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-create_join_table).

You can check the `create_join_table` code at the bottom (click on **Source: show**).

Answer (score 3):

[SchemaStatements#create_join_table()](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-create_join_table) only creates join table without any fancy indexes etc,... So if you wish to use uniqueness constraint on two fields you have to do something like this:

```
class CreateJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_join_table :posts, :users do |t|
      t.integer :post_id, index: true
      t.integer :user_id, index: true
      t.index [:post_id, :user_id], name: 'post_user_un', unique: true
    end
  end
end
```

> Please also note that `create_join_table` by default does NOT create `id` field.

Answer (score 0):

Also be aware of how you define the dependent destroy for this join table.

If you later move away from HABTM and define the relationships using `through:` and get it wrong you might run into the 'to_sym' error I reported [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/34782).

Make sure you have defined the destroy like this:

```
class Proposal < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :products, through: :assignments, dependent: :destroy # <- HERE
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :proposals, through: :assignments, dependent: :destroy # <- HERE
end

class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :proposal
end
```

not this:

```
class Proposal < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assignments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :products, through: :assignments
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assignments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :proposals, through: :assignments
end

class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :proposal
end
```

Comment: When you put the `:destroy` statement on the `:through` relationship, wouldn't it destroy the corresponding `Product`s or `Proposal`s instead of just the `Assignment`?

Comment: @Toby1Kenobi Hmm, that's a good question. I don't know, will have to test it.