# Rails many to many update and create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm interested in creating and updating a row in table without a primary key. My table has 3 columns - person_id, year and salary. I understand that I should use has_and_belongs_to but I'm having problems understanding how to implement my create and update methods and my form.html file. Can anyone help explain this to me, perhaps with a simple example of how to do it?

Comment: checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120703/creating-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-rails-3

Comment: (person_id, year) seems like a natural primary key, but Rails doesn't support composite keys. You can try this gem however: http://compositekeys.rubyforge.org/

Answer (score 0):

has_and_belongs_to_many example

```
# category model
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end

# user model
class User < ACtiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end
```

join table look like

```
class CreateCategoriesUsersJoinTable < ACtiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :categories_users, :id => false do |t|
      t.integer :category_id
      t.integer :user_id
    end
  end
end
```

now you can accessing your information

```
$ User.categories
$ Category.users
$ user = User.first
$ user.categories
$ category = Category.first
$ category.users
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a primary key, and ignore it. You can add a unique index on (person_id, year) to simulate a PK constraint, but ActiveRecord heavily relies on having ids for its instances.