# Ruby on Rails NoMethodError on call to object.each

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nomethoderror

I have `show` action in the `Exhibitor` model. I want to display a list of `Meetings` for which the `Exhibitor` is a `Sponsor`.

`Exhibitor` model:

```
class Exhibitor < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :description, :name, :exhibitor_category, :sponsor,    :exhibitor_category_id

 validates :name, :presence => true
 validates :description, :presence => true
 validates :exhibitor_category, :presence => true

 belongs_to :exhibitor_category
 belongs_to :sponsor
 end
```

`show` action:

```
def show
    @exhibitor = Exhibitor.find(params[:id])
    @sponsoredmeetings = @exhibitor.sponsor

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @exhibitor }
    end
  end
```

`show` view:

```
    <p>
    <b>Meetings:</b>
    <% @sponsoredmeetings.each do |c| %>
    <%= c.meetings %>
    <% end %>
    </p>
```

When I run the page I get this:

> NoMethodError in Exhibitors#show
>
> undefined method `each' for # Rails.root:
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/eventmanager
>
> Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
>   app/controllers/exhibitors_controller.rb:17:in `show' Request
>
> Parameters:
>
> {"id"=>"1"} Show session dump

What am I doing wrong on the controller page to keep getting this error?

Comment: What does your exhibitor model look like?

Comment: can you include your exhibitor model in your question?

Comment: You haven't got meetings inside your model. Is the attribute `meetings` part of your exhibitor table?

Answer (score 0):

The error is connected with `@sponsoredmeetings.each` in your view.

`@sponsoredmeetings` has value of `@exhibitor.sponsor`, and `sponsor` attribute, as I can see in your model, is not something returning collection but a single object, so there is no `each` method for object returned by this attribute. You have `belongs_to` connection from `exhibitor` to `sponsor`, so **one** `exhibitor` belongs to only **one** `sponsor`.

If you would like to create one to many relationship, where one exhibitor has many sponsors, you should replace

```
belongs_to :sponsor
```

with

```
has_many :sponsors
```

If you want many to many relationship (many exibitior has many sponsors and sponsor has many exhibitors), check `has_and_belongs_to_many` connection described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120703/creating-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-rails-3).

Of course, if your database schema has one to many relationship, where one sponsor has many exhibitors (as your `exhibitor` model suggests) and you want to change your models in one of proposed ways, remember to update relationships in database.

Be sure to read more about [associations in rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).