# Rails adding many to many association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-migrations

i have a "Question" model and a "Tag" model. I added a many-to-many association to these two model.
that's what i have now :

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :score, :title
   has_and_belongs_to_many :tags

end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :name
   has_and_belongs_to_many :questions
end
```

What should i do to update the database and the controllers ?

thanks

Comment: check if this helpfull http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120703/creating-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-rails-3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a migration for the join table with the following command:

```
$ rails g migration questions_tags question_id:integer tag_id:integer
```

Create the table in the database:

```
$ rake db:migrate
```

Rails magic will help you populate the join table.  I created a [many-to-many code quiz](http://www.codequizzes.com/learn-rails/many-to-many-relationships) with a has_and_belongs_to_many example that you might find helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can consult with Rails Guide on associations [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association). Here's a code snippet right from there:

```
# Models
class Assembly < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :parts
end

class Part < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :assemblies
end

# Corresponding migration for creating models and join table
class CreateAssembliesAndParts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :assemblies do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps
    end

    create_table :parts do |t|
      t.string :part_number
      t.timestamps
    end

    create_table :assemblies_parts do |t|
      t.belongs_to :assembly
      t.belongs_to :part
    end
  end
end
```