# Create a Intern messagerie between two users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

I wonder how I create an internal messagerie like twitter or Facebook between two users with Ruby on rails.

What is the table with Main and foreigners keys do I use?

Have I to do `Messagerie/id/User_id/` But there are two Users.

Which `belongs_to` and which has `has_many`?

Do you know what I mean. Thanks for your precious help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120703/creating-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-rails-3

Comment: @PavelOganesyan Thank you my question is how to create an intern Messenger? What can I do nest to have an interaction between 2 users?

Comment: Ok, let's consider another approach. If you don't need chats with multiple users you can make message with 2 fields - `senderID` and `receiverID`. When current user opens chat with another one you can select all messages where these 2 users are sender or receiver.

Comment: @PavelOganesyan That looks interesting. If I understand the table will be: Senders/id/user_id/message_id   &  Receivers/id/sender_id/message_id but if they answer, the sender will be receiver and vice-verca how could you controll this?

Comment: No, table Messages will have columns Id, Text, Sender, Receiver, Sent_at.
You can select messages  for 2 users as `Messages.where('sender IN (?) and receiver IN (?)', %w(user1Id, user2Id), %w(user1Id,user2Id))`

Comment: @PavelOganesyan Do I place this following code `Messages.where('sender IN (?) and receiver IN (?)', %w(user1Id, user2Id), %w(user1Id,user2Id))` in my controller?

Comment: Yes, in the method that shows chats. But it depends on design of your application. Such code can also be placed in model. I guess, you need a good tutorial about basics of RoR applications design. Maybe, this one with chat example - http://josephndungu.com/tutorials/gmail-like-chat-application-in-ruby-on-rails It uses quite same scheme but adds Conversation objects.

Comment: @PavelOganesyanThank you the tutorial looks like full!