# has_many through - accessing attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model called Offer

```
class Offer < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :sections
  has_many :offer_items, through: :section
end

class Section < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :offer
    has_many :offer_items
end

class OfferItem < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :section
    belongs_to :offer
end
```

After seeding the database like this:

```
offer = Offer.create(name: "Offer A")
section = offer.sections.create(name: "Section A")
item = section.offer_items.create(name: "Item A")
```

The item is not created and if I want to access offer_items like `Offer.first.offer_items` it gets me an error:

```
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the association :section in model Offer
```

I can also see that `OfferItem.attribute_names` returns every attribute but no `offer_id` so it seems like the other belongs_to is not working.
What is going on here?

Comment: I think this has been asked before. Check out this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5120734/2891994

Comment: try : `has_many :offer_items, through: :sections`. the `through` value must match another association (error explains that pretty good)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not

```
has_many :offer_items, through: :section
```

It's

```
has_many :offer_items, through: :sections
```

You don't have a `:section` association, you have a `:sections` association.

Comment: What a stupid mistake that was. So I wasted an hour searching for tutorials but all I needed was a letter "s". Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem!  The great thing about being stuck on this sort of stuff is that you definitely remember for the next time. :)