# Display table in different view than original

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

How do I display my employee nonavailability table in my schedule view?

As I am creating a schedule for my employees I would like to see my employee nonavailability table in the view of my schedule model.

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 right">
      <% @non_availabilities = NonAvailability.all %>
      <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="col-md-2">Employee</th>
          <th class="col-md-2">Date</th>
          <th class="col-md-2">Time</th>
          <th class="col-md-2">Reason</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
      <tbody>
      <% @non_availabilities.each do |non_availability| %>
        <tr>
        <td class="col-md-2"><%= non_availability.employee.full_name %></td>
        <td class="col-md-2"><%= non_availability.date %></td>
        <td class="col-md-2"><%= non_availability.time %></td>
        <td class="col-md-2"><%= non_availability.reason %></td></tr>
      <% end %>
        </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please include your code so we can check more easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a very simple answer to my issue. To display the table of a model on a different model view all I needed was the following.

```
<% @employees.each do |employee| %>
  <%= employee.name %>
  <%= employee.position %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your employee table is a model called `Employee` and your schedule form is a model called `Schedule`.

If you wanted to list all of your employees in your `schedules` show view (or any other view such as index), you can use something like this:

```
class SchedulesController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @employees = Employee.all
  end

end
```

In "Employee.rb" (model): `belongs_to :schedule`

In "Schedule.rb" (model): `has_many :employees`

And in your `shedules` show.html.erb:

```
<% @employees.each do |employee| %>
  <p><%= employee.name %></p>
  <p><%= employee.position %></p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I attempted to make it work with this code but I get the following error  "undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass". It highlights the <%@employee_table.each do |employee| %> part

Comment: @Jovany What is the name of the two models you are trying to link together? I've updated my answer, I forgot to include the relationships between each table.

Comment: Schedule.rb and employee.rb are the model names

Comment: @Jovany Cool, this solution should work. If it does don't forget to accept it as the answer, thanks!

Comment: well I attempted and it doesn't work for me. Maybe I should reclarify. I want the table of employees to show up on the form view of schedule. As I create a schedule I want to be able to see the list of employees.

Comment: @Jovany I still am not quite sure what you're going for. Please update your question with what code you have right now and a further explanation of what exactly you want where.

Comment: I honestly don't know how I can explain it any better. I assume you know what the form view is. I want to split the view in half. Half the page will be the form to create a schedule and the other half will be displaying the table of employees. the code I have is what you give me, but I want the table to display in the Shedules _form.html.erb

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @Jake is correct, just one caveat.

Let's assume you define a schedule as two-week roster, therefore relationship would become a many to many (not belongs_to) and you will need a join table.

In "Schedule.rb" (model): `has_and_belongs_to_many :employes`
In "Employee.rb" (model): `has_and_belongs_to_many :schedules`

I had a similar problem last week, this answer was helpful:
[Creating a many to many relationship in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120703/creating-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-rails)