# issue in has_and_belongs_to_many association in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

currently exists `user` with has_many `project`

but now i want to update `project` has_many `user` and `user` has_many `project`.

but i am getting error- **Could not find table 'projects_users'**

in project.rb

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :users
```

user.rb

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :projects
```

Generated migration

```
rails g migration CreateProjectsUsersJoinTable
```

Getting error as-

Could not find table 'projects_users' 
on index#controller line - @projects = current_user.projects

Comment: Out or curiosity, did you `rake db:migrate`? If so, what does your `CreateProjectUsersJoinTable` migration look like? Also, should `rails g migration CreateProjectUsersJoinTable` be `rails g migration CreateProjectsUsersJoinTable` (Projects pluralized).

Comment: @jvillian ```rake db:migrate``` has been executed i took reference from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120703/creating-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-rails

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think this might help
run `rails g migration create_project_users`
in project_users table

```
class CreateProjectUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :project_users do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :project_id
    end
  end
end
```

then user.rb

```
has_many :project_users
has_many :projects, through :project_users
```

and in project.rb

```
has_many :project_users
has_many :users, through :project_users
```

project_user.rb

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :project
```

Answer (score 1):

If your rails version is greater than 5, you can make a new migration using create_join_table.

```
rails g migration CreateJoinTableProjectsUsers project user
```

This will generate following:

```rb
class CreateJoinTableProjectsUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_join_table :projects, :users do |t|
      t.index [:project_id, :user_id]
      # t.index [:user_id, :project_id]
    end
  end
end
```

And
in project.rb

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :users
```

user.rb

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :projects
```