# Model Associations in Rails - many-to-many for multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, many-to-many, associations

I'm trying to understand and implement Active Record Associations in Rails and am having some trouble understanding how to put together the specific relationships I need.

I have a Recipe model and an Ingredients model. Many Ingredients will belong to a single Recipe and therefore, a Recipe will have many Ingredients. I am having trouble grasping how this is handled through MySQL and how to implement these relationships in the models correctly. Here is the (relatively sparse) code I have, so far:

models/recipe.rb

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ingredients
end
```

models/ingredient.rb

```
class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :recipes
end
```

However, I'm fairly certain the association line in ingredient.rb is incorrect.

How would I correctly implement these relationships?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Recipe` model should have a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship with the ingredients instead of `has_many`. This allows a single recipe to have many ingredients (i.e. you can do `@recipe.ingredients`), while a single ingredient can be in many recipes (`@ingredient.recipes`).

It does seem kind of weird when first starting out, but once you've grokked how Rails relationships work, it becomes intuitive. You're on the right track.

Comment: See this page for a concrete example: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_and_belongs_to_many-association

Answer (score 1):

A has_many relationship implements a one to many mapping while has_and_belongs_to_many implements a many to many mapping. So a has_many is paired with a belongs_to while has_and_belongs_to_many are paired together.

The relationship between Recipe and Ingredients will be a many to many one if you also want to find out relations like which recipes a particular ingredient is being used in.

To implement a has_and_belongs_to_many in a mysql db you will have to create a third join table that maps all the links between the two tables.

You can look at [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381154/rails-migration-for-has-and-belongs-to-many-join-table) to get a better idea of the format of the join table.