# Rails Many to Many SQLite3 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I created a many-to-many relationship in rails, here's my models and migrations

```
class Channel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :packages
  validates_presence_of :name
end

class Package < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :channels
  validates_presence_of :name
end

class CreateChannelsPackages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :channels_packages, :id => false do |t|
      t.references :channel
      t.references :package

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :channels_packages, :channel_id
    add_index :channels_packages, :package_id
  end
end
```

Then i have a multiple select, but when i try to save i get this error

```
SQLite3::ConstraintException: constraint failed: INSERT INTO "channels_packages" ("package_id", "channel_id") VALUES (1, 1)
```

I tried to remove the indexes from the migration but it didn't solve it, did somebody else have this problem?

Btw i'm using Rails 3.2.6 and sqlite3 1.3.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it is the reason of your problem, but the `has_and_belongs_to_many` association  is deprecated.

According to the [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_and_belongs_to_many-association-reference):

> The use of extra attributes on the join table in a has_and_belongs_to_many association is deprecated. If you require this sort of complex behavior on the table that joins two models in a many-to-many relationship, you should use a has_many :through association instead of has_and_belongs_to_many.

I know that you are not adding any extra attribute to the join table, but try changing your migration to the below, which I think is the [default](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#updating-the-schema):

```
class CreateChannelPackageJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :channels_packages, :id => false do |t|
      t.integer :channel_id
      t.integer :package_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks, using has_many :through instead of has_and_belongs_to_many worked, though has_and_belongs_to_many works normally on mysql.

The migration had nothing to do with it, i could use .references and add_index normally

Answer (score 2):

I think gabrielhilal's answer is not quite correct: use of *extra attributes* in the join table is deprecated, thus you need to remove the timestamp in your migration, then it should work just fine with the has_and_belongs_to_many wich itself is *not* deprecated.

If you do need additional attributes in your join table, though, has_many :through is the way to go.

There is also another question with good answers on this topic:
[Rails migration for has_and_belongs_to_many join table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381154/rails-migration-for-has-and-belongs-to-many-join-table)