# How to implement a follower system like Twitter with has_and_belongs_to_many association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, twitter

I am a novice of Rails. And I wanna create a tiny SNS like Twitter.
How to implement the follower system with AciveRecord in has_and_belongs_to_many?
I create a "User" table. And the follower relationship is a many-to-many logic between one user and one user.
So how to decelerate the model class and create the join table?

Comment: See this previous answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4381282/1042144

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last chapter of railstutorial is talking about what you want.
http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/following-users#top

Comment: Thanks! It's a useful book!