# Rails4 validate uniqueness of multiple columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model Friendship where :friend_id is also a foreign key as :user_id

friendships
    id | user_id | friend_id
I'm aware that validating the uniqueness of the two fields would be something like this

```
validates :user_id, :uniqueness => {:scope => :friend_id}
```

But is there a way to validate

```
user_id = 1, friend_id = 3
user_id = 3, friend_id = 1
```

so that only  user_id = 1, friend_id = 3 is stored?

Comment: why do you wan't to dissallow the second case? Isn't that a scenario where user 20 adds user 10 back?

Comment: which database u r using??

Comment: I would also suggest that you rename your model to `Friendship`, as you don't create & manage a `Friend`, rather a friendship between users.

Comment: in your case 1 you mean that data should not be repeat?? there is duplicate

Comment: I would avoid disabling second case. To be honest, this is how you should create friendship models - always both connections for each friendship, so you can easily load them (e.g. joins, includes)

Answer (score 1):

**Join Model**

Looks like you're using a `join model` with Rails - as mentioned in the comments, you'll want to change this to `friendship` (not `friend`).

Rails has two types of `join` mechanism - [`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) and [`has_and_belongs_to_many`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) - both allow you to associate `many-to-many` records, like this:

```
#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :friendships
   has_many :friends, through: :friendships
end

#app/models/friendship.rb
Class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :friend, class: "User", foreign_key: "friend_id"
   belongs_to :user
end

#friendships
id | user_id | friend_id | created_at | updated_at
```

I would recommend you have a `friendship` model (as opposed to a model-less `HABTM` setup), because `HMT` allows you to add extra data, such as `created_at`, `updated_at`, `permissions`, etc)

---

**Self Referential**

I would also use a `self-referential` model. This will allow you to keep a single model (for `User`), and then call `@user.friends` without an issue.

Whether my above association definitions are correct is another matter; this is how you'd want to set them up.

--

**Validation**

In terms of validating your associations, I believe you'll be able to use [indexes in your DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381154/rails-migration-for-has-and-belongs-to-many-join-table). This is used often for `HABTM` tables -

```
#Migration

# Adding the index can massively speed up join tables. Don't use the
# unique if you allow duplicates.
add_index(:friendships, [:user_id, :friend_id], :unique => true)
```

This will work for your original case, but not for the second